# How to write to Synapse dedicated sql pool

Tags: python, apache-spark, azure-synapse

Looking for options to load incremental data from either parquet/deltaLake to Synapse sql warehouse using spark notebooks.

Answer (score 0):

[Analyze data with dedicated SQL Pools:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/get-started-analyze-sql-pool)

Above docs has information about creation of dedicated SQL Pool by loading FILE_TYPE = PARQUET data.

[Analyze data in a storage account:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/get-started-analyze-storage)

Above docs analyze the data in your workspace default as we can link Blob storage account to your workspace through Create CSV and Parquet files in your storage account

[Load data in dedicated SQL Pool using copy activity:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/quickstart-copy-activity-load-sql-pool)

Above docs gives us insight about loading data as copy activity.

[Analyze data with Spark and Notebook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/get-started-analyze-spark)

Above docs will helps us in creating a spark pool